# DLL uses another DLL in C++

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I have a complex 3rd DLL by C++. (I compiled it and have .lib both).
I want to write a new my simple DLL, that using a few function in the 3rd DLL.

How to import a 3rd DLL in my DLL?

(Now, i got an error, When importing 3rd to my DLL, i could not load my DLL in any other application)

Comment: Simply link against it, and have it available for runtime loading. Can you be a bit more precise in what you've tried and how that didn't work?

Comment: Your program will need to be able to find *all* the used DLLs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue, A stupid issue.
My 3rd DLL uses too much another DLL.

I missed a library, (I developed my App by C#, It did not notify me missed library)